# Check characters inside string for their Unicode value

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8

I would like to replace characters with certain Unicode values in a variable with dash. I have two ideas which might work, but I do not know how to check for the value of character:

1/ processing variable as string, checking every characters value and placing these characters in a  new variable (replacing those characters which are invalid)

2/ use these magic :-)

```
$variable = s/[$char_range]/-/g;
```

char_range should be similar to `[0-9]` or `[A-Z]`, but it should be values for utf-8 characters. I need range from 0x00 to 0x7F to be exact.

Comment: The character range from 0x00 through 0x7F is exactly ASCII, so why drag UTF-8 into this?

Comment: There's no such thing as UTF-8 characters. There are only characters that you encode into UTF-8.

Comment: thanks for clearing that out, btw this is interesting http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html#UTF-8-vs.-utf8-vs.-UTF8

Answer (score 3):

The following expression should replace anything that is not ASCII with a hyphen,  which is (I think) what you want to do:

```
s/[\N{U+0080}-\N{U+FFFF}]/-/g
```

Comment: negation does affect whole range not just starting and ending value? Should not it be s/[\N({U+0080}-{U+FFFF})]/-/g

Comment: \N{} means Unicode, not negation.  Negation in a character class uses the caret symbol ^.  For instance [^0-9] matches anything that is not in the range 0 to 9.

Comment: The easier way to do that is to use the negated property: `\P{ASCII}`. For a particular ordinal value, it's a bit cleaner to use `\x{#####}`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as UTF-8 characters. There are only characters that you encode into UTF-8. Even then, you don't want to make ranges outside of the magical ones that Perl knows about. You're likely to get more than you expect.

To get the ordinal value for a character, use `ord`:

```
 use utf8;
 my $code_number = ord '';  # U+1F638

 say sprintf "%#x", $code_number;
```

However, I don't think that's what you need. It sounds like you want to replace characters in the ASCII range with a `-`. You can specify ranges of code numbers:

```
 s/[\000-\177]/-/g;  # in octal
 s/[\x00-\x7f]/-/g;  # in hexadecimal
```

You can specify wide character ordinal values in braces:

```
 s/[\x80-\x{10ffff}]/-/g;  # wide characters, replace non-ASCII in this case
```

When the characters have a common property, you can use that:

```
 s/\p{ASCII}/-/g;
```

However, if you are replacing things character for character, you might want a transliteration:

```
$string =~ tr/\000-\177/-/;
```

Comment: Why would I do that? I'm not replacing 國. I know you're new to Perl, but, as you've noticed, you get a lot wrong. You might want to step back and just read the answers for a bit. Or, learn Perl.

Comment: use ord, thats a nice way to do that